# How to proper uninstall a windows 8 phone app deployed from visual studio?

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have deployed some samples from visual studio. I wanted to remove them from the phone again and did it from the phone uninstall.
Now i cant deploy the sample again, it fails the deployment everything. If i create a new phone app there is no problem deploying that.
How do i proper remove apps when deployed from visual studio and how do get the sample working again that i broke from uninstalling it from phone.

Comment: When you uninstall the app from the phone it should have uninstalled . When you said deployment failed ... Can you provide what is the error message you received ?

Comment: "Have you tried turning it off and on again?" @ https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C2Ph8zwpNyI . Restarting the phone normally solves any lingering deployment issues from development time.

Comment: I've got this problem too. Only happened after hundreds of uninstalls, but now the app is "stuck" - it's not listed in the apps, but Visual Studio gives "Error Installation of the application failed. The application is already installed, or update or uninstall is running." If you run the WP Developer Power Tools you'll see the app is still listed but there's no option to delete. If I find a solution (that doesn't require a reset) I'll post it here. [Edit just noticed the date of this post - thought it was Jan 2015 at first! Well, still seems relevant as have the same problem.]

Answer (score 2):

Very old but if anyone still have this problem, I've found the solution here:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0ec5dd19-330b-4575-ad41-a25399e4f083/wp-81-deployment-error-installation-of-the-application-failed-the-application-is-already?forum=wptools&prof=required

1. Install [Windows Phone Power Tools (CodePlex)](https://wptools.codeplex.com/)
2. connect to device and remove all dev apps from isolated storage
3. be happy

Answer (score 1):

Just tap and hold the app icon in the "all apps" list in the phone or in the emulator, context menu shows up and there click the "uninstall" option, that's all.

Comment: I uninstalled on the phone as you wrote, but then i could not deploy again from visual studio. I found a app installed with the SDK to deploy .xap packages to install it again. Dont know if that is intended.